# wp_add_object_terms cant recognize a post ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i'm facing a weird problem.
I have a cutom post type 'cpt_dates' with a taxonomy 'cpt_dates_postIDs'. I need to save as a taxonomy term an ID of another post (from another CPT, freshly inserted with `$cpt_dates_post_ID = wp_insert_post`).

The thing is I don't understand why. Because in all websites I've seen they said to use `intval()` because the function seems to wait for a numeric number.

... or I missed something

```
$cpt_dates_post_ID = wp_insert_post( $dates_insert_args, true );

var_dump($cpt_dates_post_ID); // int(68);
```

### WORKS :

```
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, strval($another_post_id), 'cpt_dates_postID');
```

### WORKS :

```
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, 'foo', 'cpt_dates_postID');
```

### DOESN'T WORKS :

```
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, intval($manifestation_insert_id), 'cpt_dates_postID');
```

Thank you !
Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, intval($manifestation_insert_id), 'cpt_dates_postID');
```

You're actually saying "Add a `cpt_dates_postID` term with ID `intval($manifestation_insert_id)` to the CPT with ID `$cpt_dates_post_ID`".

That won't work, because `intval($manifestation_insert_id)` is the ID of:

> another post (from another CPT, freshly inserted with [...]

Not the ID of an existing `$cpt_dates_post_ID` term entry.

The reason why these 2 work:

```
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, strval($another_post_id), 'cpt_dates_postID');
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, 'foo', 'cpt_dates_postID');
```

Is because you're passing a string as the 2nd parameter. In that case, WordPress will create a new term of type `cpt_dates_postID` with name `strval($another_post_id)` or `foo`.

Off the top of my mind, you could do this instead:

```
// Create the term entry
$term_ids = wp_insert_term( strval( $another_post_id ), 'cpt_dates_postID' );

// Assign it to your post
wp_add_object_terms( $cpt_dates_post_ID, $term_ids[0], 'cpt_dates_postID');
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer, I'm actually on it, I'll let you inform about the result ! Thank's !

Comment: In fact, I use "wp_create_term" :
Adds a new term to the database ... "if it does not already exist".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ignazio.
I ended up with this one, and it works (for now) :

```
$post_object_id = wp_insert_post( $dates_insert_args, true );

$new_term_or_not = wp_create_term( $manifestation_insert_id, 'cpt_dates_postID' );

if( is_wp_error( $new_term_or_not ) && $new_term_or_not->errors["term_exists"][0] != "") :

    $term_to_inset_id = $new_term_or_not->error_data["term_exists"];

else :

    $term_to_inset_id = $new_term_or_not["term_id"];

endif;

wp_add_object_terms( $post_object_id, $term_to_inset_id, 'cpt_dates_postID');
```